# How to build a dynamic mysql query to suit all users

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

I need your help with my website search functionality. I'm developing a members area wherein users can search other registered users based on certain criteria, or combination of criteria.

My problem now is how to build a dynamic mysql query to suit the need of each combination of search criteria, where the number of criteria is variable.

Normally, I can write with a pre-determined set of criteria using

```
   WHERE param1 = '$param1'
   AND param2 = '$param2'
   AND param3 = '$param3'
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You might need to provide more information (your schema, query space, existing code...).  Or I suppose we could guess.  Is the answer [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29)?  What do I win?

Comment: Is the issue that you want any of the criteria to be true, or that you want one query where a given number of criteria are true?  What I mean is, should if be more like `WHERE a = '$a' OR  b = '$b' OR c = '$c'` or more like `WHERE a = '$a' AND  (b = '$b' OR c = '$c')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issue is that you don't know which of the criteria the user will pick, but want to return results for "blank" criteria, you can use the following:

```
$criteria_1 = $_POST['criteria_1'];
$criteria_2 = $_POST['criteria_2'];
$criteria_3 = $_POST['criteria_3'];

if(!$criteria_1 && !$criteria_2 && !$criteria_1) {

     echo "You must select at least one criteria!";

} else {

   // Run query mentioned below and return results.       

}
```

THe query would then look like:

```
SELECT * from mytable
WHERE
(criteria1 = '$criteria_1' OR '$criteria_1' = '') AND
(criteria2 = '$criteria_2' OR '$criteria_2' = '') AND
(criteria3 = '$criteria_3' OR '$criteria_3' = '')
```

This will treat any blank (non-selected) parameters as blank and ignore them.  Be aware that with the above, if no criteria are given, it will return all results.

Another way to write the above is:

```
SELECT * from mytable
WHERE
criteria1 IN ('$criteria_1', '') AND
criteria2 IN ('$criteria_2', '') AND
criteria3 IN ('$criteria_3', '')
```

Again, allowing for no entry at all to return all criteria1 results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In a situation whereby the user fails to input any criteria. Can't i stop the quey form running altogether, by checking for.............. 
        if (('$param1' = "") &&('$param2' = "")
        && ('$param3' = "")) {
        echo "All Fields are Empty";
        exit();
}

thanks for the help.

Comment: You're saying you want to return no results if all criteria are blank?

Comment: You could do this before running the query at all, yes. Edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic example of what you're asking:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";

if ($_POST['name'] == "Jack") {
   $query .= " WHERE name = 'Jack'";
}
if ($_POST['name'] == "Bob") {
   $query .= " WHERE name = 'Bob'";
}

if ($_POST['state'] != "") {
   $query .= " AND state = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($state) . "'";
}

//So now, in total, your query might look like this
//"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = 'Bob' AND state = '$state'"    

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

You just add to your `$query` string with `if` statements, then execute the query once you've checked all `$_POST` variables.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen queries like this, so that if you don't want to put in a value for a particular column, you pass in NULL for that column:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE param1 = :param1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE param2 = :param2
UNION
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE param3 = :param3
```

This assumes that you'll have each column indexed and you're performing Boolean AND searches (and using PDO).

Answer (score 0):

use your scripting language (php) to loop over the inputs...

then have a structure like this:

```
WHERE 1=1
```

then add your

```
AND paramx = '$px'
```

to it...

Answer (score 0):

```
$criteria = array();

//Populate your criteria and parameter arrays with input from the web page here
...
// $criteria should now have stuff in it

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable ";//Or whatever your sql query is
$count = 0;
foreach ($criteria as $key => $parameter) {
  if ($count == 0) {
    $sql = $sql."WHERE ".$key." = ".$parameter;
  } else {
    $sql = $sql."AND ".$key." = ".$parameter;
  }
  $count++;
}
```

That said, this is highly vulnerable to sql injection attack. Try using [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

An option is also to build the query from php/asp or whatever you working with, like this

```
$param1 = (isset($searchParam1) ? "param1 = $searchParam2" : "1");
$param2 = (isset($searchParam2) ? "param2 = $searchParam2" : "1");
$param3 = (isset($searchParam3) ? "param3 = $searchParam3" : "1");
```

and the query would be like

SELECT ... WHERE $param1 $param2 $param3

Answer (score 0):

would like to share this code to build dynamic mysql query  with PHP
Thx & regards

```
$vocabulary = (($page == "vocabulary") ? "image_name <> ''" : ""); 
$groupcat = (($group != "") ? "group = $group" : ""); 

$var = array($vocabulary, $groupcat);   

$counter = "0";
$param = "";
for ($i=0;$i<count($var);$i++)
{
    if ($counter == "0" && $var[$i] != "" )     $param = "WHERE ";
    if ($counter > "0" && $var[$i] != "" ) $param = " AND ";

    if ($param  != "") 
    {
        $condition .= $param . $var[$i];
        $param="";
        $counter++;
    }
}   
echo "Condition : ". $condition;
```